# "The Local repository is out of date"....i have no branch how to solve this

Tags: git, xcode8

When we push the code to the remote server Xcode shows the below warning. Also see the attached screenshot

> The Local repository is out of date.

[image: Screenshot]

I have no branch or any other working copy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

that warning is because someone else would have pushed to your repo after the last time you pulled from it. you will need to pull from the repo, merge your code and then you will be able to push again

Comment: I have this same problem. I tried pulling and it says I am already up to date. Should I force push?

Comment: Im a single developer team, I don't even know how this is possible!?

Answer (score 20):

I had the same issue I solved it like that :

first go to the Project directory in your terminal

```
git init
git add .
git stash save
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master
git pull -r
git stash pop
git push
```

let me know if it works

Comment: That was the answer for me. I couldn't find a way around the error on XCode.

Comment: This helped me too, though I do not like using terminal.

Comment: Doesn't `git init` create a completely new repository?

Comment: git init is not creating a new repository it will just set up a git project, it will not affect your remotes or branches

Comment: How do I reverse this? I just lost all my work without any backup

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue and it happened because I added the README.md file from the GitHub website by creating another branch to add it.
Xcode does not pull changes made through the website automatically.

So you have to go to Xcode menu and select Source Control -> Pull.

[image]

And then I checked "Rebase local changes onto upstream changes", this applies local commits one at a time. I had many commits I didn't push, so I chose this.

[image]

Comment: Be careful of the The Golden Rule of Rebasing. Never use it with branches others are working on like main/master. Your main history will start to diverge from the one everyone else is working on, and this will likely cause headaches later.

A good summary:
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing#the-golden-rule-of-rebasing

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue, but I knew for sure I was up to date locally; team of one, although I think some git changes I did from the command line confused Xcode.

What eventually seemed to work was some combination of the following;

in Xcode:

1. Source Control -> Fetch Changes
2. Source Control -> Pull, with rebase option (nothing should happen if you're already up to date)
3. Source Control -> Reset File Status
4. Quit Xcode (don't just close the project, quit the app)

Then from a command prompt at the root of your project folder, do similar but also reset to origin/main (adjust accordingly):

```
(base) ➜  PROJECT git:(main) git fetch                                 
(base) ➜  PROJECT git:(main) git pull 
Already up to date.
(base) ➜  PROJECT git:(main) git reset --hard origin/main              
HEAD is now at 7a169f4 chore: still working through Xcode annoyance saying local repo is up to date.
(base) ➜  PROJECT git:(main) git pull                    
Already up to date.
(base) ➜  PROJECT git:(main) git fetch
(base) ➜  PROJECT git:(main)
```

Then go back in to Xcode, make one dummy change, commit and push it. It worked for me and the warning was now gone.

This was on Xcode 14.2, MacOS Ventura 13.1.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you get that out-of-date error when your local and remote repository are not in sync. You need to pull the changes from the remote repository by running git pull.
I find that Xcode makes it hard to use version control your code, You can find `git pull` in Xcode under Integrate -> git Pull.

and then try again Integrate -> push

[image]