# How can I revert to original state after git stash?

Tags: xcode, git

I was getting an error while trying to push changes from XCode to remote git repo.

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49392319/3128638) which made me lose all my project files. The only remaining are the .xcodeproj and Pods directory. How can I revert to original state after calling this commands

```
git init
git add .
git stash save
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master
git pull -r
git stash pop
git push
```

Just learnt my lesson on following instructions without understanding.

Comment: @matt can't I was pushing my first commit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier for you to use and understand `git` if you use git client like https://gitup.co/

It clearly shows you -

1. all of your current local & remote branches
2. where your HEAD is

It has a dedicated view for adding/deleting stashes as well. For each stash, you can view the diff in a very readable way.

Install the app, open your `git` repository using this app & it will show you exactly what is the state of your current repo.

It will also show you the git stashes you have saved locally & allow you to pull/push from/to remote in an easy way.

Comment: Thanks, I am playing around with this at the moment trying to figure out how I can revert the whole project. Some relief because I can see my files using the Diff view